# How do I get URL parameters?

Tags: rust, iron

Something wrong with below code (I'm absolutely new in Rust...):

```
let function = move |req: &mut Request| -> IronResult<Response> {
    let router = req.extensions.get::<Router>().expect("Unable to get router");
    println!("router:{:?}", router);
    let val = router.find("param").expect("param is required");
    ...
}
...
router.get("/page", function, "handler");
...
```

While executed (site/page?param=0), got below traces. Looks like 'router' is empty. What's is wrong ?

```
router:Params { map: {} }
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'param is required', src/main.rs:xx:xx
```

So, I decided to use `params::{Params}` and almost reached my goal, but...

```
let function = move |req: &mut Request| -> IronResult<Response> {
    use params::{Params};
    use crate::iron::Plugin;

    let map = req.get_ref::<Params>().unwrap();
    let val1 = map.find(&["param1"]).expect("param1 is required");
    let val2 = map.find(&["param2"]).expect("param2 is required");
    let cmd = format!("cmd={:?}{:?}\n", val1, val2);
    println!("{}", cmd);
    ...
};
```

I get `cmd="1600","100"` instead of wanted `cmd=1600,100`. Can't use `format!({})` due to compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: `params::Value` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
`params::Value` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
```

Tried different string/number conversions but failed since `val1`, `val2` are not strings but `params::Value`. Tried remove quotes from `cmd` string but also failed. Any idea of simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

The params of the `Router` are those specified in the URL pattern e.g. if you define a route `GET /:query` then you'll get a `query` param storing the corresponding path segment.

The querystring you access via [`Request::url`](https://docs.rs/iron/0.6.1/iron/request/struct.Request.html#structfield.url).